# Find the intersection of two survival functions with proportional hazards.

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

Let be $X,Y$ random variables with hazard functions: $h_X(x),h_Y(y),$ respectively, such that: 
$$h_X(x)=kh_Y(x), k>0.$$
Find the intersections of the survival functions $S_X(t), S_Y(t).$

My attempt:
$$S_X(t)=S_Y(t)$$
$$exp[-\int_0^tkh_Y(u)du]=exp[-\int_0^th_Y(u)du]$$
$$k\int_0^th_Y(u)du=\int_0^th_Y(u)du$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}k\int_0^th_Y(u)du=\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^th_Y(u)du$$
$$kh_Y(t)=h_Y(t)$$
$$(k-1)h_Y(t)=0$$
$$h_Y(t)=0$$
So, the intersection is in $t=h_Y^{-1}(0)$ only if $h_Y^{-1}(0)$ exists.

Answer (score 0):

I was with you up to here:
$$k\int_0^th_Y(u)du=\int_0^th_Y(u)du\tag1$$

but not here:
$$\frac{d}{dt}k\int_0^th_Y(u)du=\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^th_Y(u)du$$

The equation (1) is equivalent to $S_X(t)=S_Y(t).$ Assuming $k\neq 1,$ this means that $S_X(t)=S_Y(t)$ if and only if:

- $\int_0^th_Y(u)du=0$, or
- $\int_0^th_Y(u)du=\infty$

These correspond to $t$ in the intervals $[0,m]$ and $[M,\infty),$ where $m=\inf\{t\mid S_X(t)<1\}$ and $M=\sup\{t\mid S_X(t)>0\}.$

For example, consider a population $X$ where people cannot die before the age of five, and [always die after 21](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logan%27s_Run). Consider another population $Y$ with the same structure, except everything is a hundred times as hazardous. The survival functions will match precisely for $t\leq 5$ and $t\geq 21.$